# open the insert menu using google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like google sheets apps script to be able to open the insert menu choose drawing and pick the scribble tool automatically so a person could do a signature and then it would be placed in a certain place.

It that possible.?

Comment: No, you can not manipulate the menu from app script.  I would make a custom dialog or sidebar for that.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a library to handle the signature like [this](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad). Then you can place the resulting image into your document.

1. Add the library to a Editor-on Website:
2. On the page from step 1 call the signing widget

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);
```

3. Let the user sign it and add some button
4. Grab the image using and send it to the server for handling

```
// let the user sign and export it
const jpg = signaturePad.toDataURL("image/jpeg")
google.script.run.storeImageToSheet(jpg)
```

I think in step 4 you cannot just send an image but rather have to encode it to base64 in order to be sent. Then on the server on step 5 you can [decode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64Decode(String)) the image and use it. This is a suggestion on my end, whether that works, but technically I am 90% sure.

In step 5 you would do something like

```
// Insert the image in cell A1.
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(binaryData), 'image/jpg', 'MyImageName');
  Active_Sheet.insertImage(blob, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Neven, how do you send the <canvas> or <img> to Google Spreadsheet.  I envision something like `google.script.run.sendImage(image)` but how do you get the image to render in Spreadsheet.  I tried toDataURL() but all I get is a black box.

Comment: see above for a modified answer which outlines the broad steps to take.

Comment: Thank you Neven. You have now opened up a mind blowing thing for me as I don't know how to add library etc. YET. My own solution was to make up any signature using the drawing canvas and tell the user to edit it themselves.